# Using Apps as content for in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ipa

I'm looking for a way to download iPhone apps (or just the .app content of the Payload folder) as an in-app purchase.

I work with a company who has built their entire asset library in Flash and we're now trying to get it mobile. I know this isn't ideal but with Flash CS5.5 we can export the Flash to a .ipa. While we could ship each course as its own app, we're trying to achieve a more streamlined experience (think the Marvel Comics app). Ultimately I'd like to write the Container App in Xamarin.

Is there anyway to make these "apps" or their payload non-consumable content through an in-app download and can someone point me in the right direction for launching them? I'm not trying to get around Apple's security provisions or in-app purchasing rules so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow IAPs to be code.  You can't use IAPs to distribute apps.  You can have an advertisement in your app that features the other apps, but there's no mechanism to purchase one app from another.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I know you can't compete against the App Store and distribute apps but surely they have to allow some code. Otherwise, is there a list of accepted file types you can point me at to help answer this?